# Flutter GlobalKey usage conundram

Tags: flutter, dart

I apologize for the vague title but I couldn't figure out a better way to phrase it, so my big issue with Flutter's GlobalKey is first, for the same widget I believe its only supposed to exists once in the entire widget tree, now I have a widget that I use in multiple other widgets, having declared the GlobalKey in all these parent widgets I saw a complaint and upon reading about it, I came to this realization.

Now, some online suggestions say that I should declare the keys somewhere and then import them and reuse them for all the occurances of the same widget, sounds like a good idea but am still in doubt, this is supposed to work and if it does, won't it pickup the instance of the first occurance of the widget across the app. Another question is, is there an alternative to GlobalKey that I can use in this sense (`_key.currentState!.widgetFn(some_param)`).

I have searched and experimented various ways and I still haven't made a breakthrough on this and would really appreciate your help on this, thanks in advance.